# Features for blink detection in real-time single channel EEG

Tags: time-series, feature-extraction

I am looking to detect blink events in real-time single channel EEG. Classification of a moving window of samples to determine whether a blink artifact exists requires feature extraction (except when using deep learning, I am not experienced enough for this). What features would be useful to extract from a window of approx. 50-200 samples of time series data for detecting a blink event. The blink event can be easily seen in the below picture:
[image: Blink event in EEG data]

Answer (score 0):

I would try a combination of the following:

- A rolling-window variance to detect unusually large deflections
- [Bollinger bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollinger_Bands) to detect the spikes
- [Autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) to detect the 'up down up' pattern